Wix toolset v5 Dialog not displayed
[SOLUTION] How can I fix a Wix 4 bundle installation where dialogs are not displayed?
In a wix Bundle I install a package.
This package is supposed to display a custom dialog to give end-user ability to set some parameters.
The dialog is never shown, do you have some ideas ?
Here is the bundle file.
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
     xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal"
    xmlns:ui="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui"
    xmlns:util="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/util"
    xmlns:netfx="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/netfx">
    <Bundle Name="MyApplication"
            Manufacturer="Yes"
            Version="$(Version)"
            UpgradeCode="7592386d-5261-4457-8914-394b7fc9f1c5">
        <BootstrapperApplication>
            <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
                LicenseUrl="https://www.yes.com/license"
                Theme="hyperlinkLicense" />
        </BootstrapperApplication>

        <Chain>
            <PackageGroupRef Id="BundlePackages" />
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>

    <Fragment>
        <PackageGroup Id="BundlePackages">
            <PackageGroupRef Id="PrereqPackages" />
            <MsiPackage Id="OpenPackage" SourceFile="OpenPackage.msi" />
        </PackageGroup>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <PackageGroup Id="PrereqPackages">
            <ExePackage SourceFile="./Prerequisites/VC_redist.x64.exe" InstallArguments="/quiet /norestart" Permanent="yes"/>
        </PackageGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>

And the Package file part of OpenPackage.msi
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
    xmlns:ui="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/ui"
    xmlns:util="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/util"
    xmlns:netfx="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/netfx">
    <Package
        Name="Open"
        Manufacturer="Indeed"
        Version="$(Version)"
        UpgradeCode="7b065815-517e-4e68-afff-1188ebf8403c">
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="!(loc.DowngradeError)" />
        
        <UI>
            <Dialog Id="InstallDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName] [Setup]" NoMinimize="yes">
                <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="{\DlgTitleFont}Ready to Install">
                </Control>
                <Control Id="Install" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Install">
                    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" />
                </Control>
            </Dialog>
            <TextStyle Id="DlgFont8" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
            <TextStyle Id="DlgTitleFont" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" Bold="yes" />
            <InstallUISequence>
                <Show Dialog="InstallDlg" After="CostFinalize" />
            </InstallUISequence>
        </UI>
        
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
        <Feature Id="Main">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="OpenServiceComponent" />
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="OpenArtifactComponent" />
        </Feature>
    </Package>
</Wix>

The installed files are correct but the dialog is not displayed.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
